# How to each nth line a a column using awk?

Tags: text, awk, gawk

I have a single column text file looking like this:

```
John
Doe
Male
1984
Marie
Parker
Female
1989
```

And I would like to convert it to look like this:

```
John Doe Male 1984
Marie Parker Female 1989
```

I've tried using `awk` and modulo but I cannot manage to find a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ pr -4at file

John              Doe               Male              1984
Marie             Parker            Female            1989
```

or your format

```
$ pr -4ats' ' file
John Doe Male 1984
Marie Parker Female 1989
```

of course with `awk`

```
$ awk 'ORS=NR%4?FS:RS' file

John Doe Male 1984
Marie Parker Female 1989
```

with `paste`

```
$ paste -d' ' - - - - < file
John Doe Male 1984
Marie Parker Female 1989
```